# Сontrollability problems in linear systems

Tags: control-theory

In my control theory task and have example, it's just first step of task
[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to get some tips how do they go from 1 to 2 cases

In my task I have 4 material points and only get this while transforming from 1 to 2 (I think it's wrong)

$$
\begin{cases}
 m\ddot{x_1} = -c(x_1 - x_3) - c\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x_1 + u\cos{\alpha} \\
 m\ddot{y_1} = -c(y_1 - y_4) - c\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}y_1 + u\sin{\alpha} \\ \\
 m\ddot{x_2} = -c(x_2 - x_4) - cx_2 + u\cos{\alpha} \\
 m\ddot{y_2} = -c(y_2 - y_3) - cy_2 - u\sin{\alpha} \\ \\
 m\ddot{x_3} = -c(x_3 - x_1) - c\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}x_3 + u\cos{\alpha} \\
 m\ddot{y_3} = -c(y_3 - y_2) - c\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}y_3 + u\sin{\alpha} \\ \\
 m\ddot{x_4} = -c(x_4 - x_2) - cx_4 - u\cos{\alpha} \\
 m\ddot{y_4} = -c(y_4 - y_1) - cy_4 + u\sin{\alpha}
\end{cases}
$$

$$
\begin{cases}
 x_{11} = -\frac{c((2 + \sqrt{2})x_{12} - 2x_{32})}{2m} + \frac{u \cos{\alpha}}{m}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Could you please translate the Russian into English? It would provide more context for your question.

Comment: It's Ukrainian, but I ready solve this, thanks to @emma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's written right above 2: they define $x_1=\dot{x},$ $x_2=x$, $x_3=\dot{y}$ and $x_4=y.$ Replace these definitions in 1 and you're almost done. The equations in 2 are called *state space representation* of 1.

Edit: Hang on, So the part that you have marked with 1 is clear to you, right?

Comment: No 1 it's just example

Comment: I just don't understand why $\dot{x_2} = x_1$ and $\dot{x_4} = x_3$

Comment: By definition $x_1=\dot{x}$ and $x_2=x.$ This implies $\dot{x}_1=\ddot{x}$ and $\dot{x}_2=\dot{x}=x_1.$ For $x_3$ and $x_4$ it's the same thing.

Comment: Can you show same more example of this? (or some links when read about this) 

Comment: It's a standard procedure to convert a differential equation of order $n$ to a system of $n$ differential equations of order 1 by introducing a vector $z=(z_1,z_2,...,z_n)^T=(x,\dot{x},...,x^{(n-1)})^T.$ See  [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Reduction_to_a_first-order_system) for example

Comment: Some examples can be found [here](http://www.math.poly.edu/courses/ma2132/Notes/MA2132EquationsToSystems.pdf) too.